# Newly registered user to match with existing in db member

Tags: sql, asp.net, security

I have a database that contains my company clients info. We want to enable those clients to register on our website and see their data. How should be newly registered user matched with Client entity in our database? Should it be manually done by administrator? If so, what data do we need to identify them? SHould the admin be informed by an email?

Comment: These questions should rather be answered by your company's domain experts.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question on five sites simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of privacy.

**INSECURE SOLUTION**
If you don't mind the possibility of someone seeing your client's info, I would suggest the following:

- Provide a form for your clients where they enter their customer ID (if they know it) or simply their full name
- Match this info to your database and present a pre-filled form to your clients that they only need to check for changes.

**SECURE SOLUTION**
Send an email to all of your clients asking them to register using their code (you send them their personal code in this email and you can match this to your database).

Alternatively, you can let your clients enter all of their information and manually match this to the client entity in your db. I cannot suggest this, but if you want to do this, check it on a daily basis.